# Oracle APEX Report Query - Show All row as default

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I'm creating a report table where users can select a filter that would filter out the table values depending on what selection they make.
(i.e. if they choose company1, then only rows with company1 will show up).

I'm having issues with trying to allow the user to see all the values of the table again (getting rid of the filtered value).
My current query is this:

```
select 
       TRANSACTION_NUMBER,
       SUPPLIER,
       DATE_

  FROM Table1 b join Account a on b.SUPPLIER = a.companyname
    where 

        Supplier =
          (CASE
              WHEN USERTYPE(:APP_USER) = 1 THEN :P2_Supplier
              ELSE (select COMPANYNAME from Account where lower(USERNAME)=lower(:APP_USER))
          END)

    AND
     PURCHASE_DATE_AND_TIME >= TO_DATE(:P2_START)
      AND PURCHASE_DATE_AND_TIME < TO_DATE(:P2_END)+ 1
```

I would like it to be when **supplier = NULL**, the table shows all the values (aka getting rid of the "where" portion of the query.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work? It's not tested since the original query wasn't executable...

```
select 
  Supplier...,

  FROM Company b join Account a on b.SUPPLIER = a.companyname
    where 
      (:P2_Supplier is null or
        Supplier =
          CASE
              WHEN USERTYPE(:APP_USER) = 1 THEN :P2_Supplier
              ELSE (select COMPANYNAME from Account where lower(USERNAME)=lower(:APP_USER))
          END
      )
```

Comment: hmm it didn't work. i'll update the query above so that you could try it out.

Comment: Is it possible it didn't work because of the PURCHASE_DATE_AND_TIME predicates you have after?

Comment: Oh actually, I tried it out again and it did work :) thank you so much!!!